# How is the std::shuffle_order_engine table managed?

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, stl, c++14

When I call `operator()` on a `std::shuffle_order_engine` will a new number immediately be generated to refill the lookup table? Or, will numbers be used up from the table and only when a missing number is required the table refilled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call will have one or more calls to the underlying PRBG that adapter contains  From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/shuffle_order_engine/operator()):

> Generates a random value. The state of the underlying engine is advanced one or more times.

Answer (score 1):

The `operator()` function will advance the state of the engine, and will return a generated arbitrary value.

*will a new number immediately be generated to refill the lookup table?*

Each of the constructors fills the table with *n-values* returned by the base engine.

*Or, will numbers be used up from the table and only when a missing number is required the table refilled?*

The engines transition algorithm picks a value from the table when a value is requested. So it will be used up from the table.